# Encoding.UTF8 or Encoding.Unicode?

Tags: .net, unicode, encoding, utf-8

Is [`Encoding.Unicode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.unicode) just a name for UTF-16? Then why is it called just Unicode instead of UTF16?

In the [encoding documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding#Selecting) Microsoft states that for most scenarios and applications you should avoid using `Encoding.ASCII` and `Encoding.Default`.

When using [`System.Text.Encoding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding). In most scenarios should I be using `Encoding.Unicode` or `Encoding.UTF8`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is `Encoding.Unicode` just a name for UTF-16?

Yes. Specifically, for little endian UTF-16. `Encoding` has a separate `BigEndianUnicode` property for big endian UTF-16.

> Then why is it called just Unicode instead of UTF16?

For historical reasons.  Microsoft was one of the 1st companies to adopt Unicode, so it had a "Unicode" implementation in Windows way back in the early days of Unicode before UTF-16 was invented. "Unicode" is Microsoft's de-facto name to refer to whatever its native Unicode encoding is, which used to be UCS-2 and is now UTF-16.

> When using `System.Text.Encoding`. In most scenarios should I be using `Encoding.Unicode` or `Encoding.UTF8`?

That really depends on your particular scenarios.  Use whichever encoding suits your needs. Both encodings have strengths and weaknesses.

UTF-8 is commonly used for interoperability in communications protocols, as it doesn't suffer from endian problems, and is largely compatible with most existing textual based protocols. It is also *usually* smaller for byte storage than UTF-16 for most languages.

UTF-16 is *usually* easier to process in memory than UTF-8, which is why so many libraries and frameworks use it for Strings. And it *can be* smaller for byte storage than UTF-8, especially for Eastern Asian languages.

Comment: Well which one should I use for most of the cases, most of the time, in most of the applications? Which should be my "go to" variant? UTF-8 or UTF-16?

Comment: @Fred In many languages since VB4, UTF-16/UCS-2 is used for text data types (String, Char, Character). So it is natural to use those there. Also the Windows API and NTFS use it, so same there. In SQL Server, NCHAR/NVARCHAR is the only way to process Unicode text. On the UTF-8 side, JSON is required to be UTF-8 when transfered between systems. Ultimately, the chosen character encoding is metadata that must be shared between writer and readers.

Comment: @Fred again, it depends on your particular needs for whatever you are planning on using `Encoding` for exactly. You are asking an opinionated question. My *opinion* is UTF-8 is usually sufficient, but UTF-16 has uses, too

Answer (score 3):

It comes from the early days of Unicode. Unicode 1.0 was a 16 bit encoding as it was assumed that 65536 code points would be sufficient. Unicode 2.0 abandoned this restriction, however early adopters of Unicode, including Microsoft, Named their encoding Unicode and it has stuck.

Nowadays you should be using UTF-8 unless you have a specific, eg legacy software you need to integrate with, reason to do so.

The reason for this is that ASCII is binary compatible with UTF-8, and there is a **lot** of ASCII out there

Comment: I get that I should prefer UTF-8 over ASCII. But is `Encoding.Unicode` the same as UTF-16? And should I use `Encoding.UTF8` or `Encoding.Unicode`?

Comment: `Encoding.Unicode` is the same as UTF16 and by default you should be using `Encoding.UTF8`. I assumed that was clear from my answer

Comment: "There is a lot of ASCII out there": The encoding is what the author chose. In the PC world (since 1981), it's been pretty hard or impossible to choose ASCII. It wasn't available in MS-DOS; it's not the default for any operating system (that I know of) and hardly any programs. The reason for this is that there was a big push to have a bigger character set as the default. Unfortunately, what was available at the time was dozens of character sets with about <= 256 codepoints. Bottom line: _Read with the character encoding that was used to write._